# Error providing access to other users on Google Cloud AutoML

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, user-roles, automl, google-cloud-automl

I am using a service called Google Cloud AutoML Natural Language Processing.
Click here for more information on the product I am using:

https://beta-dot-custom-vision.appspot.com/text/overview

Everything is working fine and I need to say the product is amazing!
I managed to train a machine learning model in a couple of hours and make some predictions.

Now, I want to provide another user in my organisation with the right to access the User Interface of this product, so that this user can make his own predictions.

I connected to the Google Cloud console, created the user and assigned him three roles, which are the same that a service account would need, in order to access the service.

```
roles/automl.editor
roles/ml.admin
roles/storage.admin
```

Now, when the user tries to connect to the UI of this service, he gets a white page with the following error message:

"Exception while handling your request. When reporting refer to this issue by its tracking code tc_571165"

There is no more information, nor a trace of the issue anywhere in the google cloud console. 
What am I missing? This service from Google is still in Beta, so probably it's just a bug.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In my use case, I share my vision model to my colleagues by creating a service account for them with the right role and give them this URL for prediction:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer add_access_token " -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/id_project/locations/us-central1/models/:model_idpredict -d @path_of_image_in_base64
```

And it works!